# How to get Timer Tick Event to interrupt another function C++/CLI

Tags: c++, events, timer

I am new to C++/CLI, I am coming from a background of using embedded C++. I have created a temperature controlled block that can communicate with a PC to set/read temperatures.

I am trying to create a program that cycles through different temperatures and takes readings at 1 second intervals. I have used a "Forms Timer" which is supposed to Tick every second and create an "event" which like in embedded C, should "interrupt" my BtnTestTemp_Click() function.

```
private: System::Void LogTempTimer_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    GetTemp_Click(sender, e);
    tempreadingNb++;
}

private: System::Void BtnTestTemp_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    //SET TO ROOM TEMP
    this->TempSet->Text = "2500";
    SetTemp_Click(sender, e);
    //WAIT UNTIL 2500 +/- 1
    while ((currenttemp > 2600)||(currenttemp < 2400)) {}
}
```

When not in my BtnTestTemp_Click() function, the timer works fine and i can see it calls the LogTempTimer_Tick() event every second. However, when sitting in my while loop:

```
while ((currenttemp > 2600)||(currenttemp < 2400)) {}
```

The LogTempTimer_Tick() function is never called and the current temp is never updated.

Why does the event not trigger during another function? What should I be doing to get it to "interrupt" the other function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That type of timer is made for a single threaded application. IE the same thread that is currently executing in the button click is the one that would be used to execute the timer tick. So it cannot execute that event until the other event is completed.

Check out the Timers in System.Timers for something that can be used in a multi threaded environment